# convert transparent area inside a shape to solid so I can fill with color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency, fill

I downloaded a vector image from ShutterStock and edited it to the colors as shown. I want to make the inside of each shape the same color, but about a 50% opacity level, but can't in its current state as the inside of the shapes are part of a transparent background.

How can I convert these transparent areas within the colored shapes so I can adjust the coloring inside the shape for Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Use the Live Paint Bucket tool and just click.

Answer (score 2):

Just like @Scott has simply put it, the Live Paint Bucket tool will help you pull it off. Let me try to expound it for you.

**1.** I tried to recreate your Vector, composed of two compound parts, the Red petals(Rose) and Green leaves and stalk(Stalk).
[image]

**2.** Select the Rose path, and then choose the  *Live Paint Bucket*  from the Tools panel or shortcut key <kbd>K</kbd>. Make sure you select a contrasting *Fill*. Then Hover over the Insides of the Rose and click away. **Note** that the 'Rose' compound path is converted into a 'Live Paint' Group in the layers panel.

[image]

**3.** Go to Menu (**Object > Expand**) to expand the Live Paint group. Make sure the Object, Fill and Stroke options are all selected.

[image]

**4.** Use the *Direct Selection Tool* <kbd>A</kbd> to select one painted path inside the group, go to Menu (**Select > Same > Fill Color**), then group these paths <kbd>Ctr + G</kbd>. Do the same for the outside colored paths.

[image]

**4.** Change the color of the inside group to match the outside (Eyedropper Tool <kbd>I</kbd>) and change its opacity to 50%.

**5.** Repeat steps [2-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF1jM.jpg) on the *Stalk compound element*.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to select the petals and use **"Divide"** tool in the **"Pathfinder"**.
[image]

You can now select the transparent part that you want to color by moving an anchor point of the initially colored element with **arrow keys**. Then select the transparent element by double-clicking it with the selection tool.
[image]

Now you can select the color you want for the transparent element and move back **(arrow keys again)** the anchor point to its original place.
[image]